# is every triangulation of regular n-gon has same minimum angle?

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation

Although my knowledge maybe not correct, but I will state it nonetheless;

"Delaunay triangulation maximizes the minimum angle among all triangulation"

"Every triangulation of regular n-gon satisfies Delaunay condition, as no point is in interior of circumcircle of any triangle formed, therefore they are all valid Delaunay triangulation."

Then, If I am not mistaken, does every triangulation of regular n-gon have same Inf angle, because they all maximizes the minimum angle, and they are all Delaunay?

Comment: Every angle is opposite an edge connecting two vertices of the $n$-gon.  It equals half the angle from vertex to centre to other vertex, so is a multiple of $\pi/n$.  The smallest angle is always $\pi/n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every angle is opposite an edge connecting two vertices of the $n$-gon.  It equals half the angle from one vertex to the centre to the other vertex, so is a multiple of $\pi/n$.  The smallest angle is always $\pi/n$.